# How can I rename file extensions to another extension type, on another directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, forfiles

I'm attempting to rename all files with the file extension of ".ACH" to ".TXT" on another directory.

I used the below batch file on my local machine and it works like a charm:

```
@Echo Off
CD C:\Users\jonsmith\OneDrive\PC\jonsmith-PC\Desktop\TestingBatch Rename
forfiles /S /M *.ACH /C "cmd /c rename @file @fname.TXT"
```

However, when I attempt to use the same syntax on the server, nothing happens:

```
@Echo Off
CD D:\AP\ACHTest Rename
forfiles /S /M *.ACH /C "cmd /c rename @file @fname.TXT"
```

I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong, but something tells me it's how I'm using the `CD` command.

Comment: Replace `cd` by `cd /D` to also change to the drive, or use `forfiles`' `/P` option to specify the root directory. *N. B.:* Use a standard `for` loop rather than `forfiles`: `for /R "D:\AP\ACHTest Rename" %%I in ("*.ach") do rename "%%~I" "%%~nI.txt"`…

Comment: @aschipfl that was perfect!

Comment: Always glad to be of service! Please do not include solutions in your question, please post an answer instead! You can even accept your own answer then…

Answer (score -1):

I don't want to force Batch, so I have an easier way.
Inside file1.ach:

```
Hello
```

Inside file2.ach:

```
Hi
```

Code:

```
del file1.ach
del file2.ach
```

Current directory:

```
echo Hello >>file1.txt
echo Hi >>file2.txt
```

Different directory:

```
echo Hello >>D:\MyWork\TestRename\file1.txt
echo Hi >>D:\MyWork\TestRename\file2.txt
```

Easy, without forcing anything.

Comment: Hm - what do you do when the files have hundred or thousands of lines?